# IBM MQ vs Apache Kafka as a message broker/engine for Event Driven Architecture and Microservices Architecture

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, mq, microservices, event-driven

**Context:** My company uses WebLogic AppServer and Oracle Service Bus for SOA service orchestration and choreography. We would like to move forward to an event-driven, microservices architecture. The key point is to eliminate the complex of service orchestration in back office.

**Question:** What is the recommended message engine for an event-driven, microservices architecture? If performance and high through put are not our top concerns. Our biggest concern is the guaranteed delivery, fail-over, and system Resilience. **Resilience** can be achieved in different ways in MQ and Kafka.

Also consider: "**Dumb pipe, smart endpoint**" as a principle, is Apache Kafka more appealing, plus resilience?

Any thoughts and opinions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix [MessageHub](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html) service is based on Kafka and is designed for microservices architecture.